# Too many arguments to function call "c"

Tags: c, cs50

I am trying to use a function to print a quantity of characters. The quantity of the characters is dependent on an integer provided by the user, and a for loop.

```
int get_height(void);
string printsp(void);
string printhash(void);

int main(void)
{
    //running function for getting height
    int h = get_height();

    //setting up the column numer i
    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
    {
        printsp(h - 1 - i);
        printhash(i + 1);
        printsp(2);
        printhash(i + 1);

        printf("\n");
    }
}    

//prompting for integer within parameters
int get_height(void)
{
    int h;
    do
    {
        h = get_int("Height: ");
    }
    //Keeping i betwwen 1 and 8 inclusive
    while (h > 8 || h < 1);
    return h;
}

//printing the spaces
string printsp(void)
{
    printf(" ");
}

//printing the hashes
string printhash(void)
{
    printf("#");
}
```

I keep getting that there are too many arguments in the function calls. I am new to this.

Comment: Hint: how many argument do your functions take, and how many do you pass them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Too many arguments to function call “c”

You declare `printsp` and `printhash` without a parameter but you call them with a parameter, this is non consistent.

You need a parameter and to use it, and you do not use the value return by the functions so better to have them `void`

you want something like (minimum changes) the declarations

```
void printsp(int n)
void printhash(int n)
```

and (minimum changes) definitions :

```
//printing the spaces
void printsp(int n)
{
  while (n-- > 0)
    printf(" ");
}

//printing the hashes
void printhash(int n)
{
   while (n-- > 0)
    printf("#");
}
```

also `printf` just for a char is expensive, you can just use `putchar`, and there are other possibilities to improve the printing.

---

So for instance :

```
int get_height(void);
void printsp(int n);
void printhash(int n);

int main(void)
{
    //running function for getting height
    int h = get_height();

    //setting up the column numer i
    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
    {
        printsp(h - 1 - i);
        printhash(i + 1);
        printsp(2);
        printhash(i + 1);

        putchar('\n');
    }
}    

//prompting for integer within parameters
int get_height(void)
{
    int h;
    do
    {
        h = get_int("Height: ");
    }
    //Keeping i betwwen 1 and 8 inclusive
    while (h > 8 || h < 1);
    return h;
}

//printing the spaces
void printsp(int n)
{
  while (n-- > 0)
    putchar(' ');
}

//printing the hashes
void printhash(int n)
{
   while (n-- > 0)
    putchar('#');
}
```

With these definitions the result entering 5 is :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
    Height: 5
        #  #
       ##  ##
      ###  ###
     ####  ####
    #####  #####
    pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

---

Note however `printsp` and `printhash` can be a unique function also receiving in argument the character you want to print

```
int get_height(void);
void printch(int n, char c);

int main(void)
{
    //running function for getting height
    int h = get_height();

    //setting up the column numer i
    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
    {
        printch(h - 1 - i, ' ');
        printch(i + 1, '#');
        printch(2, ' ');
        printch(i + 1, '#');

        putchar('\n');
    }
}    

//prompting for integer within parameters
int get_height(void)
{
    int h;
    do
    {
        h = get_int("Height: ");
    }
    //Keeping i betwwen 1 and 8 inclusive
    while (h > 8 || h < 1);
    return h;
}

//printing ch n times
void printch(int n, char ch)
{
   while (n-- > 0)
    putchar(ch);
}
```

Comment: iostream is C++, this is C.

Comment: @Barmar oh yes, I suposed C++ because of `string`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I implemented and got 'control reaches end of non-void function' and reference to the { at the end of the function

Comment: @EdCase did you change `string` to `void` as I did ?

Comment: @EdCase I edit my answer to put all the definitions, and an execution

Comment: @bruno I had not done all of the changes. It compiles now, but does not do what I wanted. Time to re-think I think. Thanks for your help

Comment: @EdCase no problem, happy codding

Answer (score 0):

`printsp(void)` means that this function does not take any arguments.

Same for `printhash(void)`.

```c
for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
    printsp();
    printhash();
    printsp();
    printhash();
    printf("\n");
}
```

Would be the correct usage.

Also your functions (`printsp` and `printhash`) should return a `string`, not nothing!

Comment: I'll bet those two functions are supposed to take an argument that indicates how many spaces or hashes should be printed.